# How can I create pagination dots in React using Tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, tailwind-css

I have a couple of images, and in mobile screen view I am using snapping to show 1 image at a time and the user can scroll right to the next image.

I want to put some pagination dots under the image to show the user that he/she can scroll to the right for more image.

```
const NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 4
const [currentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

return(
<>
<div className="flex flex-row overflow-scroll no-scrollbar snap-x snap-mandatory">
        <img  src={screen1} alt="Playstore image1" className='flex-none w-[100%] h-[100%] object-contain rounded-sm snap-center snap-always'/>
        <img  src={screen2} alt="Playstore image2" className='flex-none w-[100%] h-[100%] object-contain rounded-sm snap-center snap-always'/>
        <img  src={screen3} alt="Playstore image3" className='flex-none w-[100%] h-[100%] object-contain rounded-sm snap-center snap-always'/>
        <img  src={screen4} alt="Playstore image4" className='flex-none w-[100%] h-[100%] object-contain rounded-sm snap-center snap-always'/>
</div>

<div>
{Array.from({ length: NUMBER_OF_PAGES }, (_, i) => i + 1).map(item=>(
    <div className='w-5 h-5 bg-slate-600 rounded-full shadow-md mx-4'/>
))}
</div>
</>
)
```

How can I track the currently selected image, and change the styling depending on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by conditionally adding a class depending on whether the index of each pagination dot is equal to the currently selected page:

```
{Array.from({ length: NUMBER_OF_PAGES }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((item, index)=>(
      <div className={`w-5 h-5 ${currentPage == index ? "bg-blue-600" : "bg-slate-600"}  rounded-full shadow-md mx-4`}/>
))}
```

If you update your code with the JSX snippet above, the currently active pagination dot (ie: the dot matching the current page) will be styled differently to the non-active dots.

You can update this as you see fit; for the purposes of this example, I styled the active pagination dot to be blue. As the user moves through the images, the active pagination dot will then update.

Comment: How do I update the currentpage state? With each card selected the state remains the same :/